# Biblatex - How to access the "saveddate" using "\entrydata*"?

Tags: biblatex

I'm building a bibdriver with bilatex, and using `\entrydata*` to retrieve information from another entry, but at the same time, I need information of the enclosing entry. Biblatex does provide a mechanism for that, precisely the starred version of `\entrydata` which "will clone all fields of the enclosing entry, using field, counter, and other resource names prefixed with the string 'saved'."

This works fine for most fields, but I can't seem to find a way to access the enclosing entry's date fields. Dates are, of course, special fields (hat tip to moewe) and are printed with `\print<datetype>date`. But it seems there is not a "saved" datetype. So, how could I access the "saveddate" using `\entrydata*`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mybook,
    author = {Author},
    title = {Book Title},
    date = {2018},
}

@customa{myentry,
    author = {Buthor},
    title = {My entry's title},
    date = {2017},
    xref = {book},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \printnames{author}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{title}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \entrydata*{mybook}{%
        \printnames{author}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \printfield{title}%
        \newunit\newblock
        \printtext{Which contains:\space}%
        \printnames{savedauthor}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \printfield{savedtitle}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \printdate%
        %\printsaveddate  % <- this doesn't work
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \printtext{\thefield{entrykey}}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \printtext{\thefield{clonesourcekey}}% <- this prints nothing
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \entrydata{\thefield{clonesourcekey}}{\printdate}% this doesn't work either
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \printtext{\mkbibdateshort{savedyear}{savedmonth}{savedday}}% following David's suggestion in the comments: adds unwanted bce string
    }%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printtext{\mkbibdateshort{year}{month}{day}}% no bce string here
    \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\fullcite{myentry}

\end{document}
```

**Update**: I tried to use a nested entrydata to achieve this. I thought of accessing `savedentrykey`. Turns out it has a special name `clonesourcekey`. With that I thought of using `\entrydata{\thefield{clonesourcekey}}{\printdate}`. But somehow I couldn't get it to work either. `\thefield{clonesourcekey}` prints nothing there. I updated the code to include this attempt.

**Update 2**: Following David's suggestion in the comments (or approximately so) I attempted to use `\mkbibdateshort{savedyear}{savedmonth}{savedday}`. But somehow the date thus produced gets an unwanted (and unwarranted) bce string.

Comment: No doubt @moewe will supply the correct answer in time. But I guess you could temporarily copy `savedyear`, `savedmonth`, and `savedday` to `year`, `month`, and `day`. Then call `\printdate`. :)

Comment: @DavidPurton, that's actually a very good idea, if it turns out we can't use the whole date (or if it is too complicated to do so). And I don't even have to copy it, the operation is being done within the `entrydata*` group. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This was a bug fixed in version 3.11 of `biblatex`.
>
> If you are experiencing a similar issue, please update your TeX distribution to make sure you have the current version of `biblatex` and Biber.
>
> The rest of the answer is left for historical interest.

`biblatex` does indeed not support saving date fields properly at the moment. Please test https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/684.

With the changes it is possible to use

```
\printsaveddate
```

to simply print the saved date as you would expect.

---

A temporary workaround based on David's idea

```
\printtext{\mkbibdateshort{savedyear}{savedmonth}{savedday}}
```

is also possible.

We just need to provide a few extra macros that were not automatically saved.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mybook,
    author = {Author},
    title = {Book Title},
    date = {2018},
}

@customa{myentry,
    author = {Buthor},
    title = {My entry's title},
    date = {2017},
    xref = {book},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\gusbrs@datemeta#1{%
  \csdef{ifsaved#1dateera}##1{\ifcsstring{abx@field@saved#1dateera}{##1}}%
  \csdef{ifsaved#1enddateera}##1{\ifcsstring{abx@field@saved#1enddateera}{##1}}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \printnames{author}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{title}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \entrydata*{mybook}{%
        \printnames{author}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \printfield{title}%
        \newunit\newblock
        \printtext{Which contains:\space}%
        \printnames{savedauthor}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \printfield{savedtitle}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \printdate
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \gusbrs@datemeta{}%
        \printtext{\mkbibdateshort{savedyear}{savedmonth}{savedday}}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\fullcite{myentry}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: moewe, yet again, a thousand thanks!! I'm onto something, and that's why I'm giving you so much trouble. You saved my day twice this week already. It's really appreciated! I will test things on github and report there.

Comment: Btw, can you explain why I couldn't access `\thefield{clonesourcekey}` from within the `\entrydata*` group? I would expect to be able to.

Comment: @gusbrs AFAIK `clonesourcekey` is only present if an entry was cloned, it gives the key of the entry the currently process entry is a clone of. Entries are cloned for the `related` feature. But entries are not cloned for `xref`. Especially not in your situation where both entries were `\nocite`'d and you access `mybook`'s data directly. I don't think you can ever say that `clonesourcekey` is `savedentrykey`.

Comment: @gusbrs The fact that `savedentrykey` was not provided was a bug that should also be resolved with the mentioned pull request.

Comment: But the `related` macros use precisely `\entrydata*` as their base, don't they? And `\entrydata*` is supposed to perform a clone, as far as I understood from the documentation. But it's OK! This is just curiosity, what interests is already very well provided for. Thanks!

Comment: @gusbrs The problem is that there are two ways to 'clone' an entry. `\entrydata` clones entries purely on the `biblatex` side by copying fields to `saved...`. `clonesourcekey` is about cloning of entries with Biber. Biber clones entries by writing the same entry with a different entrykey (some kind of hash) to the `.bbl`. The implementation of `related` uses `\entrydata` and also Biber-cloned entries. But that does not mean that `\entrydata` uses Biber-cloned entries.