# Can't access saved<key> within \entrydata*

Tags: biblatex

Trying to loop over child entries within a modified `set` driver in `biblatex` I get a behaviour of `\entrydata*` I do not understand.

When calling

```
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
    \message{^^Jxset Warning: inside loop for ##1^^J}%
    \entrydata*{##1}{\message{^^Jxset Warning: entrydata check loop run for entrykey=\thefield{entrykey} with savedentrykey=\thefield{savedentrykey}^^J}}}%
  \edef\xset@tempa{\thefield{entryset}}\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\xset@tempa}%
```

within the driver I get

```
xset Warning: inside loop for A:V1
xset Warning: entrydata check loop run for entrykey=A:V1 with savedentrykey=
xset Warning: inside loop for A:V2
xset Warning: entrydata check loop run for entrykey=A:V2 with savedentrykey=
```

where `savedentrykey` should - as far as I understand it - be `A` and not empty.

Even

```
  \entryset{\message{^^Jxset Warning: entryset pre code executed^^Jentrykey=\thefield{entrykey} savedentrykey=\thefield{savedentrykey}}}
           {\message{^^Jxset Warning: entryset post code executed^^Jentrykey=\thefield{entrykey} savedentrykey=\thefield{savedentrykey}}}%
```

does not work (which probably should???)...

Any idea what I am missing?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[doi=false,defernumbers=true,backend=biber,subentry,sorting=nyt,sortsets=true,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newlinechar=`\^^J

\makeatletter
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Set{A,
  entryset    = {A:V1,A:V2,A:V3},
}
@Book{A:V1,
  author      = {Rene Goscinny and Albert Uderzo},  title       = {Asterix der Gallier},
  maintitle   = {Asterix und Obelix},               sorttitle   = {Asterix und Obelix 01},
  year        = {1959},                             isbn        = {1234567890123},
  publisher   = {Dargaud},                          location    = {Paris},
  volume      = {1},
}
@Book{A:V2,
  author      = {Rene Goscinny and Albert Uderzo},  title       = {Asterix und Kleopatra},
  maintitle   = {Asterix und Obelix},               sorttitle   = {Asterix und Obelix 02},
  year        = {1968},                             isbn        = {2345678901234},
  publisher   = {Dargaud},                          location    = {Paris},
  volume      = {2},
}
@Book{A:V3,
  author      = {Rene Goscinny and Albert Uderzo},  title       = {Asterix als Gladiator},
  maintitle   = {Asterix und Obelix},               sorttitle   = {Asterix und Obelix 03},
  year        = {1969},                             isbn        = {3456789012345},
  publisher   = {Dargaud},                          location    = {Paris},
  volume      = {3},
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \message{^^Jxset Warning: entering set driver^^Jentrykey=\thefield{entrykey} savedentrykey=\thefield{savedentrykey}^^J}%
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
    \message{^^Jxset Warning: inside loop for ##1^^J}%
    \entrydata*{##1}{\message{^^Jxset Warning: entrydata check loop run for entrykey=\thefield{entrykey} with savedentrykey=\thefield{savedentrykey}^^J}}}%
  \edef\xset@tempa{\thefield{entryset}}\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\xset@tempa}%
  \entryset{\message{^^Jxset Warning: entryset pre code executed^^Jentrykey=\thefield{entrykey} savedentrykey=\thefield{savedentrykey}}}
           {\message{^^Jxset Warning: entryset post code executed^^Jentrykey=\thefield{entrykey} savedentrykey=\thefield{savedentrykey}}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Question [Biblatex - How to access the “saveddate” using “\entrydata*”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410977/biblatex-how-to-access-the-saveddate-using-entrydata) might be related...

Comment: It's late where I am and I might have missed something obvious but I get `entrydata check loop run for entrykey=A:V1 with savedentrykey=A` etc. from the `\entrydata*` as I expected. From the `\entryset` I get empty `savedentrykey`s but that was sort of expected since `\entryset` does not save the parent data (remember that usually `@set` is just a vessel for its children, it does not have meaningful data of its own). I should mention I tested with `biblatex` 3.12/Biber 2.12 and an also otherwise up to date system. What versions do you run?

Comment: @moewe 3.8a/2.8 - I'll check that...

Comment: The question you link sparked quite some changes in `biblatex` 3.11 (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/684, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/690, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/720/), so it might well be that you discovered a bug with `\entrydata*` that was fixed already

Comment: Ah yes, see my comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410977/biblatex-how-to-access-the-saveddate-using-entrydata#comment1026108_411032

Comment: @moewe If I recall correctly, most of the discussion then had to do with dates. But here, the OP is only trying to get the entrykey.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, your memory is better than mine. (I was writing the previous comment while you posted yours, and I didn't see).

Comment: @gusbrs Actually it probably isn't. I just re-read our conversation under the answer and saw that I commented on `savedentrykey` specifically.

Comment: @moewe It's polite of you to say that. ;)  So, the message to the OP is 3.11+ is required?

Comment: And now I recall why the entrykey came into the conversation. As the dates were not saved, I tried to use the `savedentrykey` to go around that.

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell the example does what it is supposed to do with `biblatex` 3.12. And there was a commit for 3.11 that specifically addressed `savedentrykey` and a few other things for `\entrydata*`.

Comment: Working after update. Thx - can you post an acceptable answer (just like update to v 3.xx)? Btw: is there any documentation about which keys can be used via saved<key>?

Comment: even more elegant: `\blx@saveentry\entryset{<pre code>}{<post code>}` works as well...  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in `biblatex` versions prior to 3.11 that would cause `\entrydata*` not to save the `entrykey`, so that `savedentrykey` would be empty. The issue was discovered and fixed when [Biblatex - How to access the "saveddate" using "\entrydata*"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410977/35864) was addressed (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/684 and in particular [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410977/biblatex-how-to-access-the-saveddate-using-entrydata#comment1026108_411032)).

With the current `biblatex` 3.12 I get

```
xset Warning: entrydata check loop run for entrykey=A:V1 with savedentrykey=A
```

from the `\entrydata*` code and

```
xset Warning: entryset pre code executed
entrykey=A:V1 savedentrykey=

xset Warning: entryset post code executed
entrykey=A:V1 savedentrykey=
```

from the `\setentry` loop.

This is the expected output: `\setentry` does not save its 'parent' data. By default `@set` is just a vessel for its child entries. It does not have useful data of its own. The only data it does have is for sorting purposes, everything else is contained in the children itself.

If you only want to access the 'parent' set name, you could use the field `entryset` as in

```
  \entryset{\message{^^Jxset Warning: entryset pre code executed^^Jentrykey=\thefield{entrykey} savedentrykey=\thefield{savedentrykey}, entryset=\thefield{entryset}}}
           {\message{^^Jxset Warning: entryset post code executed^^Jentrykey=\thefield{entrykey} savedentrykey=\thefield{savedentrykey}, entryset=\thefield{entryset}}}%
```

which would then give

```
xset Warning: entryset pre code executed
entrykey=A:V1 savedentrykey=, entryset=A

xset Warning: entryset post code executed
entrykey=A:V1 savedentrykey=, entryset=A
```

and is available in all `@set` children without additional commands.